# Role of the server for website push notifications

Tags: web-services, websocket, push-notification, server

What is the role of the server runtime environment (tomcat, jetty, etc) in creating a websocket based push notification system?

I have seen some posts that mention Weblogic 10.3.5 doesn't provide support for websockets, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen some posts than mention Weblogic 10.3.5 doesn't provide support for web sockets

You've answered your question with that last statement. The server must have support for websockets.

Websocket is a new protocol (ws://, wss://) that [offers full-duplex  communication](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html) between the server and the client. Your server must "understand" this protocol, just as it "understands" HTTP. Otherwise, when a handshake for websocket is initiated by the client, the server won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Is there some way to achieve it on such environments ?

Comment: @SagarPatni: that depends on what you are trying to do. There are libraries that allow you to create a websocket server like [TooTallNate Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), you can embed another server into your own with [webbit](https://github.com/webbit/webbit), if you want to build something around [socket.io](http://socket.io/) there is [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio). The [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) framework can also help....or upgrade the Weblogic server to a version that supports websockets, if possible.